# Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized (tweepy)

Tags: python, tweepy

I encounter a error on tweepy when I want to make a request, here is my code:

```
for tweet in tweepy.Paginator(client.get_retweeters,id=df2['Tweet Id'][0], max_results=100).flatten(limit=1000):
    print(tweet)
```

I want to have all the retweets from an tweet id. Here was a test from the first tweet id of my dataframe.

If anyone knows why I have this error, it would be very helpful.

Comment: There's some issue with your authentication code.

Comment: Just reset your system's clock.
If an API request to authenticate comes from a server that claims it is a time that is outside of 15 minutes of Twitter time, it will fail with a 401 error.